# I want an email from a google sheet when "carousel" is entered in column M with the corresponding date from whichever row "carousel" was entered in

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, notifications

```
function CheckSales() {
  // Fetch the events carousel
  var monthSalesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("M1:M1000"); 
  var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValue();
  if (monthSales = "Carousel"){
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'Carousel needs for events been added or changed' 
    var subject = 'Carousel for events';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    
    }
}
```

**I want to recieve email notifications when the word carousel is entered into column M as well as the date form whichever row "carousel" was entered on when using a shared google csheets document. THe date is in column C**

Answer (score 1):

#### Try using an installable onEdit

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 13 && e.value == "Carousel") {
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
    var message = 'Carousel needs for events been added or changed'
    var subject = 'Carousel for events';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Im getting this message  -TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onMyEdit @ Code.gs:17 in reference to const sh = e.range.getSheet();

Comment: You cannot run this type of function from the script editor.  It require an installable onEdit trigger.

Comment: Thank you  - where exactly do I go to create this installable onEdit trigger then?

Comment: The script editor menu named triggers.  The icon that looks like an alarm clock